# How to create replica with Algolia php client?

Tags: php, algolia

i am trying to link replica index to primary index using Algolia php client, i can't find anything in the index settings that flag an index as replica of primary index, just $forwardToReplicas in settings, but not creating and linking replicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create replicas you can use the "replicas" key in the settings.

```php
<?php

$client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client('application _id', 'api_key');
$index = $client->initIndex('index_name');
$index->setSettings([
    'replicas' => ['products_name_asc', 'products_name_desc']
]);
```

This will create 2 new indices "products_name_asc" and "products_name_desc".